# Why have a resource in mysql_real_escape_string?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I've been wondering for the longest time WHY I actually need a live resource to SQL connected in order to use `mysql_real_escape_string ( string $unescaped_string [, resource $link_identifier ] )`

Does this function not simply escape the data? What's the point of connecting? I want to use the function without a connection, I'm debating creating an account with no privileges just so I can do this.

I call a wrapper function `runSQL(user, statement)` and return an array with either the data or boolean status.

I've been thinking of making this `runSQL(user, statement, arguments-and-validation-data)`

I just want a reason. I can't find a "why" on the man page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct escaping depends in part on the current connection's character set, so it needs to know that information about a live connection.

---

Re your comment, here's a link to the manual for MySQL's C API, which is used by the PHP function:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html

It says:

> Note that `mysql` must be a valid, open connection. This is needed because the escaping depends on the character set in use by the server.

Comment: Could you provide me a link to a doc on this?

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation for mysql_real_escape_string - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

> Escapes special characters in the
>   unescaped_string, taking into account
>   the current character set of the
>   connection so that it is safe to place
>   it in a mysql_query()

Comment: Bonus round: Is there a way I could do this without being connected?

Comment: Not using the `mysql` extension, no.  Please consider using something more modern, like PDO or even `mysqli`.

Comment: I agree with the recommendation of PDO for its additional features, but it doesn't remove the requirement to be connected while using the escaping/quoting function.  All the MySQL extensions in PHP use the same MySQL C API.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to open multiple MySQL connections at a time. Usually you omit the resource parameter because you only use 1 MySQL connection in your script, and it defaults to the last opened connection.